# ODE implemetation in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, ode

How does one implement ODE in netlogo?
Right now , I use the Euler method which is solves the the given equations:

```
R[t+1] = r[t] + v[t] * step-size
V[t+1] = v[t] + f    * step-size
```

Found this similar [question](http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/what-is-the-good-way-to-solve-ODE-in-a-netlogo-model-td4865544.html), but it suggest uni-directional link from mathematica to netlogo which is makes it not possible to implement.

I looking for something similar to ode solver in matlab?

Comment: The question you link to has an implementation of using 4th Order Runge-Kutta to solve an ODE in Netlogo too.  Does that not meet your needs?  Are you looking for a toolbox of different ODE numerical solvers that Netlogo can draw on to use?

Comment: I am looking to solve a 2nd order ode, so the above link is of no help there.

Comment: @JRichardSnape I have implemented the runge-kutta method in Netlogo, but it is extremely slow even at timestep =0.1 sec , I think it should be compared to Euler Method. But I don't the get how the model mentioned in the link works so fast or in this one http://academic.evergreen.edu/m/mcavityd/netlogo/Bouncing_Ball.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer, compare accuracy-runtime estimates for Euler, improved Euler and RK4

Assume that the most time-consuming part is the evaluation of the system function, i.e., the vector arithmetic of the Runge-Kutta methods are a small overhead.

Given a time interval of `T=1`, restrict the methods to 100 function evaluations. Then

- Euler performs 100 steps with step size `h=0.01` and global error of the magnitude `pow(h,1)=0.01`.
- improved Euler has global error order 2 and 2 function evaluations. Thus performs 50 steps with step size `h=0.02` and global error of magnitude `pow(h,2)=4e-4`.
- classical RK4 of order 4 and 4 function evaluations per step performs 25 steps of step size `h=0.04` with global error magnitude `pow(h,4)=2.56e-6`.

Fixing the global error at about `1e-4` one obtains inversely for number of function evaluations

- 10000 for Euler, with `h=1e-4`
- 200 for improved Euler, with `h=1e-2`
- 40 for classical RK4, with `h=0.1`

which explains speed differences if the methods are tuned for the same level of the global error.

---

The strategy for the implementation of RK4 in the ball example is for an ODE system `x'=f(t,x)`, where `x` is the, possibly very large, state vector

```
 save t0=t, x0=x
 evaluate k1 = f(t,x)
 set t=t0+h/2, x=x0+h/2*k1
 evaluate k2=f(t,x)
 set x=x0+h/2*k2
 evaluate k3=f(t,x)
 set t=t+h, x=x0+h*k3
 evaluate k4=f(t,x)
 set x=x0+h/6*(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)
```

---

In an agent based system it is reasonable to store the components of the state vector belonging to the agent as internal variables of the agent. Then the vector operations are performed by iterating over the agent collection and computing the operation tailored to the internal variables.

---

A second order ODE is transformed to a first order system as indicated in the question, `x''=a(x,x')` gets transformed to `[x',v']=[v, a(x,v)]`. The big vector of the agent system is the composed of the collection of the pairs `[x,v]` or, if desired, as the concatenation of the collection of all `x` components and the collection of all `v` components.